# Working with s3 files into Postgres effciently

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

I am currently using AWS S3 as a storage for many json files (2 million and counting).
I want to put all of these files inside a db, in a Postgres RDS.

I am currently using AWS Lambda which is parsing the files, and it is significantly slower than running it locally. In addition, the work of running the script and installing external modules in Python is pretty terrible with lambda.

Is there a quicker and more efficient way to work with S3 files, parse them and put them in Postgres without the need to download them?

It needs to run on every new file (that's why I chose lambda) and it needs to be divided to couple of tables, so it's not just putting the files as-is (the script already takes the file and parses it to the right tables).

Comment: Q : your lambda function running for existing S3 json, on local machine or AWS EC2 ?

Comment: I am not sure that I've understood the question, The lambda is running on S3 remotely

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to handle these as two separate operations? One migrating from your existing s3 solution to RDS in one bulk local operation, and the other using a lambda to catch all new files?

Comment: Existing s3 to RDS , you can use AWS EC2 then run bulk operation.

Comment: I was thinking to just download each file to an ec2, do you think it will run faster?

Comment: What the lambda function will do in this 2 step solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aws glue. But that will cost you for each job run.

Comment: I was thinking about it, will check it out soon.But isn't is just simpler to run it on ec2?

Comment: You have to keep the instance of ec2 running. where as when you are using glue. the job is run in aws. You can schedule a job when require and rest all will be handled by aws.